# What is the best way to do a simple Parent-Child drop down in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, parent

I need to do a quick and dirty `Country` --> `State` drop down relationship on a web form. I only am concerned with the states, provinces, and territories for USA and Canada, and this will be a relatively lightly used form, so a pure JavaScript solution is probably ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a JSON array:

```
array = [ { name: "United States", states: [...] }, { ... } ];
```

When the value of the dropdown changes, fill in the other drop down with the contents of the particular element from the array.